# How to bind a Docker bridge to a specific NIC?

Tags: networking, docker

Not so new to Docker, but not nearly an expert either.

I am trying to build a Docker environment where a custom bridge is connected to a specific NIC.

The use case is to have a dedicated isolated lab network running on a separate interface eth1 on my PC with devices and services which cannot see nor interfere with the office/production network which is running on eth0.

One of the containers i am going to run is a DHCP server and i only want to give out IP addresses on eth1. Obviously I don’t want to give out IP addresses to the rest of the office over eth0.
I have been reading documentation, watching videos, doing online trainings, reading blogs. To me, what i want to achieve is something very basic, but i cannot seem to find how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, I think you can try to create a bridge and bind it to the NIC eht1. The steps will like this:

1. edit the eth1 config file ifcfg-eth1:

   [image]
2. edit the bridge br0 config file ifcfg-br0:

   [image]
3. restart the network service: `service network restart`
4. find your docker config file and change the `DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS` into:

   `DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS="-b=br0"`
5. restart your docker server
6. create your docker with no network:

   `docker run -itd --net=none --name=dockerName yourImage`
7. set the network for your container and you need to install the tool pipework

   `git clone https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework
    cp ~/pipework/pipework /usr/local/bin/
    pipework  br0  dockerName 192.168.0.11/24@192.168.0.141`

Note: the container's IP address is 192.168.0.11, the netmask is 24, and the gateway is 192.168.0.141. You can change some setting according to your requirement. Hope this will help you.